# MySQL query performance with calculated where clause

Tags: mysql, performance

Using MySQL, 1M record table, index exists for 'some_timestamp'.

WHERE clause is using a calculation so that records can be counted for different time buckets.

Takes way to long to execute.

Is there a better, faster approach???

Here is the current code:

```
set @now = now();

(SELECT 
    "45 Days" as "interval", count(*) as "thecount"
    FROM blah.yada
    where TIMESTAMPDIFF(day,some_timestamp,@now) <= 45
        )

UNION
(SELECT 
    "90 Days" as "interval", count(*) as "thecount"
    FROM blah.yada
    where TIMESTAMPDIFF(day,some_timestamp,@now) > 45 and TIMESTAMPDIFF(day,event_timestamp,@now) <=90
        )

UNION
(SELECT 
    "the rest" as "interval", count(*) as "thecount"
    FROM blah.yada
    where TIMESTAMPDIFF(day,some_timestamp,@now) > 90 
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, just reworking your logic a bit can work wonders.

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(day,some_timestamp,@now) <= 45
```

can be changed to

```
some_timestamp >= @now - INTERVAL 45 DAY
```

and so on with the rest of your comparisons. By moving the calculation off the field, the index can be used.

---

Furthermore, you don't need the multiple queries and UNIONs either.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN some_timestamp >= @now - INTERVAL 45 DAY THEN "45 Days"
            WHEN some_timestamp >= @now - INTERVAL 90 DAY THEN "90 Days"
            ELSE "the rest"
       END AS `interval`
     , COUNT(*) AS `theCount`
FROM blah.yada
GROUP BY `interval`
;
```

Comment: Thank you for the additional suggestion re using CASE.  However, when I restructure it this way, the query takes 1.0 seconds to complete.  The ugly UNION approach takes only 0.3 seconds to produce the same results.

Comment: @Fred hmm, strange, but oddly not too surprising. You said there were a lot of rows, so it probably had to perform the grouping on millions of strings. If you were not "married" to the intervals being strings, but instead ints, it might perform much better.

Comment: The rule is "don't hid an index column inside a function call".